# Parse - Push Android - Must internal Package Name be same as external package name

Tags: parse-platform

My internal package name is

```
com.xxxx.yyy
```

however, in my Gradle file I set the name to

```
com.xxxx.zzz
```

Also

```
com.xxxx.zzz
```

is the name I use for my `Parse` app name. What name should I use in the Android Manifest? Do I have to go through the refactor process in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is yes. I refactored my package name to be the same and I am now receiving Push messages via Parse. I am sure there must be a better answer but this is what is working now.